# Managing debug and release builds with GCC make

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gnu

I'm trying to manage two different builds of the same application. I have two separate make files, one for debug and one for release, which both work off the same sources. I also have wrapper .bat files which hold the parameters to pass to make, among other things. The whole point in this is that i want to be able to keep my object files for both so compilation time is reduced.

I tried changing the extension of the object files to `.od` (as opposed to the usual `.o`) but make didn't like that too much. And i don't know how to place these objects in a separate directory, or possibly append a d to the filename.

How is this typically accomplished?

Comment: "make didn't like that too much" - means what exactly? If you change the consistently, it shouldn't be a problem. Are you writing your makefile on your own, or are you using some generator?

Comment: I'm writing everything by hand. What i mean is make didn't know the rule for making my object file. Changing the extension back to `.o` fixed that problem, but made the debug and release object files have the same names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make has builtin rules for building `.o` files, and various other types of files.  But if you want to have it build targets with a different extension that is non-standard, you have to create that rule yourself: it won't be built-in.

Luckily, that's quite trivial.  To create a rule that builds `.od` files from `.cpp` files (for example), you can just write:

```
%.od : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUG_CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

I added `DEBUG_CFLAGS` here but you can use whatever you like.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I was using the `.cpp.o:` rule, which was probably where i was going wrong.

Comment: That will build a `.o` from a `.cpp`.  If you want to build a `.od` from a `.cpp`, then `.cpp.o` won't help you, obviously.  The pattern rule syntax I provide above will work with GNU make, but if you must use other versions of make it won't work.